# How $C[a, b]$ satisfies the axioms of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My book states that the set of all continuous functions defined on a closed interval $[a, b]$ where $a ≠ b$ satisfies the axioms of a vector space.

I am understanding that this means that for the axiom of closure under multiplication, any function within that interval that we would multiply by any scalar would still be a function within that interval. I am a little confused about this. For example how does $C[2, 4]$  with scalar $0$ satisfy this? If we would multiply any function by scalar $0$, how would it still be a function within $C[2, 4]$?

Just as a comparison, I have also understood that the set of all quadratic functions is not a vector function because if we would multiply by scalar $0$, it would cease to be a quadratic function. Am I wrong about this as well? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: If you multiply a function with the scalar $0$, then the result is the zero function that has function value zero for any $x$ that you plug in. What do you mean by "quadratic function"? If you mean polynomials of order two, the set they consitute is of course a vector space.

Comment: My book says polynomials of degree two is not a vector space, only polynomials of degree two or less.

Comment: @agblt Is $x^2 + -x^2$ a second order polynomial?

Comment: agblt Please look again at what you wrote last. You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: @JohnDouma My books says the set of all second-degree polynomials is not a vector space because the sum of $x^2$ and $-x^2$ is not a second-degree polynomial and so fails closure under addition. Or is there a difference between second degree and second order?

Comment: I found here a discussion if the set of all quadratic functions is a vector space. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205762/prove-that-the-set-of-all-quadratic-functions-whose-graphs-pass-through-the-orig

Comment: @agbit Look at the first comment in your link.

Comment: @amsmath, how am I contradicting myself, the way I understand it, the set of polynomials degree two or more is not a vector spaces because it specifically exclude polynomials of less than degree two. Therefore it fails closure under addition because $x^2+-x^2$ is not a polynomial of degree two. It also fails closure under multiplication because $0(x^2)$ is not a polynomial of degree two. Since a quadratic function is by definition a polynomial of degree two (according to wikipedia!), it is also not a vector space. However, set of polynomial of degree two or less does not fail these axioms.

Comment: @agblt Ok, the set of polynomials of degree exactly 2 is clearly not a vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[2,4]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&x.\end{array}$$Then $f\in\mathcal C[a,b]$, right? And $0\times f$ is the null function, which is *also* an element of $\mathcal C[a,b]$.